# How to make installer dialog can't be dismisses

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I install external apk programmatically using below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
File file = new File(pathToAPK);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and it will automatically open the installer dialog window. My question are:

1. How do I know whether the user click the "Cancel" button or "Install" button or even just touch outside the installer dialog screen?
2. How can I make this installer dialog window to be not cancellable, which means even if the user touch outside of the dialog screen it will not close the window?

Thanks.

Comment: myDialogue.setCancelable(false); this method make your dialog box not cancellable ifuser touch outside the dialog....

Comment: @Duggu: Thanks for your answer, but how can you get the dialog window? because I can't control the activity class?

Comment: its not possible to control that activity and activity UI

Comment: @MurtazaHussain: Hi thanks for your answer. How can I use the packageManager or other class to know what the user choose or to know the installation is being started or not? thanks.

Comment: check my answer to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can track package Install/Change extra.. by registering a broadcast receiver

In you `Manifest.xml`

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"></action>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"></action>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED"></action>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"></action>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"></action>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //You will receive events here either it is installed or removed or changed...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I have tried that too, but the receiver will only get the ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED. I still want to know what kind of action will be returned if the package is start to getting installed (not finished installed). thanks.

Comment: "what kind of action will be returned " ? can you explain this part ?

Comment: I mean for the IntentFilter for receiver. Because currently I can only get the ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED in the receiver, but I don't know what kind of ACTION to put in the InterFilter when the installation process begin (after clicking the "Install" button).

Comment: PACKAGE_ADDED is for exactly that purpose, but according to documentation its deprecated from api level 14

Comment: In my case PACKAGE_ADDED will only get received after the installation is finished, not when the installation started. thanks.